# In beamer use colors that are already defined in a given color scheme

Tags: beamer, color

I'm using a table with alternating colors in beamer.  Is there a way to base the colors I use on the palette that is already defined?  In this way if I switch color themes the colors should still go well together.

http://maururu.net/2007/latex-beamer-color-palette/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Section 17.2.2 “Using Beamer’s Colors” of the Beamer manual describes how to use preset colors: The command `\usebeamercolor[fg]{<beamer color name>}` and `\usebeamercolor[bg]{<beamer color name>}` set the current color to the foreground resp. background color given by `beamer color name`. Typical values for `beamer color name` are `normal text`, `structure` or `alerted text`

Of specific interest for you are probably the palette colors (see section 17.4 of the manual) `palette primary` to `palette quaternary` and `palette sidebar primary`, etc. Themes are typically based on these colors.

You can also have a look at the `beamer/themes/color/beamercolortheme*.sty` files (in the beamer installation dir, usually under `$TEXMF/tex/latex/`) to see what colors are typically defined by a color theme.

(All section numbers refer to the beamer v3.10 manual.)