# Color Code for Warsaw (Upper Right Corner)

Tags: beamer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In beamer use colors that are already defined in a given color scheme](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8830/in-beamer-use-colors-that-are-already-defined-in-a-given-color-scheme)

In the `warsaw` theme, under the default color scheme, in the upper right corner the color is blue / purple. How do I extract this color code?

I want to use it in `/setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=white, bg=unknown_color_code}`. Basically, I will be replacing `unknown_color_code` with whatever color is in the upper right.

Comment: The answer is here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8830/in-beamer-use-colors-that-are-already-defined-in-a-given-color-scheme .

For this specific problem, set unknown_color_code to structure.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx! It's not necessary to sign your questions (as there is already a box with your username below it) or to begin them with a greeting. A tip: you can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/863/how-do-i-mark-inline-code) as I did in my edit.