# Beamer: Using a defined color for setting another one

Tags: beamer, color

I want to use the color template "block title bg" to make a box around the title of my presentation. My code is `\setbeamercolor{title}{bg=block title.bg}` but I get the error `Package xcolor Error: Undefined color 'block title.bg'`. I've been trying what says [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8830/in-beamer-use-colors-that-are-already-defined-in-a-given-color-scheme) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33764/getting-the-color-from-a-beamer-theme), but without results. I tried at some point `\setbeamercolor{title}{bg=\usebeamercolor[bg]{block title}}` and the document compiled succesfully but without the colored box around the title. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I'd also like to know where to find the appropriate list of colors and templates. The [Beamer Appearance Cheat sheet](http://www.cpt.univ-mrs.fr/~masson/latex/Beamer-appearance-cheat-sheet.pdf) provides the names but not the .fg for using in these cases. Also, MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
{
\usetheme{Pittsburgh}
\usecolortheme{rose}
\useinnertheme{rounded}
\setbeamercovered{invisible} %hace que no se vea lo que está después del pause
\setbeamercolor{titlelike}{bg=block title.bg}
=white,bg=Blue!650}%
}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\title{fancy title}
\author{John Doe}
\date{some day}
\institute{some university}
\maketitle
\begin{frame}
{fancy title}
some text
\begin{theorem}
foo bar
\end{theorem}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Sorry for the crammed example, but I don't know how to insert line breaks (mea maxima culpa).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To copy both `fg` and `bg` parts of another beamer color you can use the `parent` option of `\setbeamercolor` as in:

```
\setbeamercolor{titlelike}{parent=block title}
```

Instead, if you want to copy only one part, or simply use it in a color expression (like mixing it with another color), you can employ the option `use`. In your case:

```
\setbeamercolor{titlelike}{use=block title,bg=block title.bg}
```

Comment: Concise and elegant! Much obliged!

Answer (score 1):

In beamer, the colour `structure` is used as the base (parent) for almost all other things. So, you may use the same for frame title too. First we define a colour to be called `structure`

```
\definecolor{mycolor}{rgb}{0.4,0.4,0.7}
%% default is 
%%\definecolor{beamer@blendedblue}{rgb}{0.2,0.2,0.7} % use structure theme to change 
%%\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=beamer@blendedblue}
```

In default there is no `bg` (background) defined but we do it now like

```
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=mycolor,bg=mycolor!20}
```

With `,bg=mycolor!20` added the titles get the background box

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Pittsburgh}
\usecolortheme{rose}
\useinnertheme{rounded}
\setbeamercovered{invisible} %hace que no se vea lo que está después del pause
\definecolor{mycolor}{rgb}{0.4,0.4,0.7}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=mycolor,bg=mycolor!20}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\title{fancy title}
\author{John Doe}
\date{some day}
\institute{some university}
\maketitle
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{fancy title}
some text
\begin{theorem}
foo bar
\end{theorem}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or simply

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Pittsburgh}
\usecolortheme{rose}
\useinnertheme{rounded}
\setbeamercovered{invisible} %hace que no se vea lo que está después del pause
\makeatletter
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=beamer@blendedblue,bg=beamer@blendedblue!20}
\makeatother

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\title{fancy title}
\author{John Doe}
\date{some day}
\institute{some university}
\maketitle
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{fancy title}
some text
\begin{theorem}
foo bar
\end{theorem}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```